# Share part of WPF screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video, video-streaming

I have to share a part of my WPF application to the second window. I could not use the existing scenarios (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093002/streaming-video-of-my-wpf-application) and [here](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/03/taking-wpf-screenshots/), as those examples takes the whole desktop.

How I can set up a rectangle, within which the video can be streamed to second monitor?

Comment: were you able to come up with anything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class.  Also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538602/find-number-and-resolution-to-all-monitors).  When you have your monitors and your bounds/dimensions, you can set the `Window`'s properties as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363374/showing-a-windows-form-on-a-secondary-monitor) question to have your `Window` show on the secondary monitor.